# Blazor Server with AdSense

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, adsense

I'm very new to Google Adsense and new to Blazor, but I'm trying to connect my .NET 7 Blazor Server app to Google Adsense. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjLEVlUA7mY but I'm not seeing any ads on my site, though I can see that html is produced but I can't visibly see anything. (second image is DOM inspection).

When I published the code live, then went to Google Adsense to do the "verification" Google says, "We couldn't verify your site. Make sure the changes you made to your site are published and accessible by the Google AdSense crawler. If you’re still having issues try another method."

I'm wondering if my code is wrong, or if the verification with Blazor just won't work and if anyone has a workaround, or if there's something else I'm missing.

Here's the code (StackOverflow kept telling me I have code formatting problems even though I used their control+ K so here's a pic of the code)

[DOM Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysluK.png)

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq5CA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the Adsense script/html isn't in the INITIAL html that the adsense crawler pulls from your site, then the crawler isn't going to be able to see it.  Blazor apps have a base page and use SignalR/Javascript to inject component data and HTML into the page *after* the base page is loaded.  This makes things great for a rich web experience, but Adsense crawler isn't going to do all the SignalR stuff needed to build a page.

Comment: Yeah. I added a meta tag in the initial html and then it passed google adsense's "verification", but I still can't see the image. I'm thinking Google is blocking it until the site passes their "review" stage.